# How to show operations under addition and scalar multiplication on this set ? For proof that the set is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove or disprove that each given subset of P5 is a subspace of P5 under the usual operations.

{ p ∈ $P_5$|p′(4)=0,where p′is the derivative of p}

This is what I have so far -

It is given that p'(4) =0. So, it follows that 0 ∈ $P_5$.

So, the first condition is met. However, I unable to proceed with showing that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Any tips on that part would be super helpful!

Comment: Why do you expect the reader/helper to guess what $P_5$ is?

Comment: If $p,q\in P_5$ such that $p'(4)=q'(4)=0$, then $(p+q)'(4)=p'(4)+q'(4)=0$. Similarly, for a scalar $c$, $(cp)'(4)=cp'(4)=0$.

Comment: @amsmath From the context it is clear that $P_n$ is the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$.

Comment: "From the context" means guessing.

Comment: @amsmath That is the information given to us. If you are talking about "what I have so far," I just assume the reader knows what the statement is pertinent to.

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath I strongly assume that you ("us") have been given the definition of $P_5$. However, you don't forward this information to us.

Comment: @amsmath I assure you that that is all the information given in the question! Thank you for attempting to help, highly appreciate it :)

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath So, "the information given to us" is actually no information at all...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{K}_n$ be the space of $\mathbb{K}$-polynomials of degree at most $n$ and let $\mathcal{I}_a:=\{p\in\mathbb{K}_n[x]\mid p(a)=0\}$. Then $f\in\mathcal{I}_a$ is equivalent to $(x-a)\mid f$ (by Ruffini's theorem) so $\mathcal{I}_a=\{(x-a)g\mid g\in\mathbb{K}_n[x]\}$ (the principal ideal generated by $(x-a)$). Given that the verification is trivial. Hope this helps.